# mpi4py: How do I ensure that all sent messages gets recieved if the number of messages is unknown?

Tags: python, mpi, mpi4py

I am trying to send messages between cores (workers), but the number of messages and their destination is unknown.
What I am working on is related to matrix completion/SGD. For this I am trying to get familiarized with the MPI packet **mpi4py** for Python.

**My goal:**
Each worker has a local list with data that will be used to do some task. For a set amount of time, each worker will continuously remove items from the list, do some computation, and then send the item to another random worker. The list will quickly become empty, so the worker must also check for incoming data sent by other random workers and add it to the list. When the time is up, all workers must retrieve the remaining sent messages.


Since a worker doesn't know the number of messages that has been sent to it, I don't know how to ensure that all the messages gets received. In my attempt below, I tried to have the workers send an ending message to signal that this was the final message, but this message doesn't get received. Is this the wrong time to use recv/irecv?
The ideal solution would be to have a worker itself add the item to another worker's local queue. Is there a way to do that?

```
import random
from mpi4py import MPI
import time

comm = MPI.COMM_WORLD
rank = comm.Get_rank()
size = comm.Get_size()

others = [i for i in range(size)]
others.remove(rank)
local_queue = [random.randint(0, 100) for _ in range(5)]

timeout = time.time() + 2
while time.time() < timeout:
    req = comm.irecv()
    # Send data to random worker
    if len(local_queue) > 0:
        r = random.choice(others)
        comm.send(local_queue.pop(0), dest=r)
    # Try to retrieve sent messages
    status = req.test()
    if (status[0]):
        local_queue.append(status[1])
comm.Barrier()

# Send final message
for x in others:
    comm.send("Done", dest=x)
comm.Barrier()

# Retrieve remaining messages
for x in others:
    msg = comm.recv(source=x)
    while msg != "Done":
        local_queue.append(msg)
        msg = comm.recv(source=x)
    
print (rank, local_queue)

MPI.Finalize()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, there is a problem in your code - you are continuously posting non-blocking receives and only waiting for the completion of some of them:

```py
while time.time() < timeout:
    req = comm.irecv()
    # ...
    status = req.test()
    if (status[0]):
        local_queue.append(status[1])
```

This starts a new non-blocking receive with each iteration of the loop, no matter whether the currently active one has completed or not. I have trouble reading the Cython code of `mpi4py`, but it looks like active requests are not cancelled upon garbage collection, so there may be a resource leakage on top of the other problem here. At least, on my test system, this leads to segmentation fault. A better option is to only post a new request if the old one has completed:

```py
req = comm.irecv()
while time.time() < timeout:
    # ...
    status = req.test()
    if (status[0]):
        local_queue.append(status[1])
        req = comm.irecv()
```

Now, regarding the actual problem, your solution is almost correct. The problem is that a `"Done"` message can also be received in the first loop. To make it work, you should keep a count on the number of received `"Done"` messages in **both** loops and keep using the already posted non-blocking operation from the first loop in the second receive loop. A working implementation of this idea is as follows:

```py
import random
from mpi4py import MPI
import time

comm = MPI.COMM_WORLD
rank = comm.Get_rank()
size = comm.Get_size()

others = [i for i in range(size)]
others.remove(rank)
local_queue = [random.randint(0, 100) for _ in range(5)]

done = 0

comm.Barrier()

timeout = time.time() + 2
req = comm.irecv()
while time.time() < timeout:
    # Send data to random worker
    if len(local_queue) > 0:
        r = random.choice(others)
        comm.send(local_queue.pop(0), dest=r)
    # Try to retrieve sent messages
    [status, msg] = req.test()
    if status:
        if msg != "Done":
            local_queue.append(msg)
        else:
            done += 1
        req = comm.irecv()

# Send final message
for x in others:
    comm.send("Done", dest=x)

if done == len(others):
    req.Cancel()
    req.Free()
else:
    # Retrieve remaining messages
    while True:
        msg = req.wait()
        if msg != "Done":
            local_queue.append(msg)
        else:
            done += 1
            if done == len(others):
                break
        req = comm.irecv()

print (rank, local_queue)
```

Notice that I've placed a barrier before the first loop and removed the other barriers. It is often the case in MPI that one rank starts way earlier than the rest and hence a barrier before the first parallel operation brings all ranks in sync. The later barriers do no good. Also, in the rare but possible case where a rank receives all `"Done"` messages in the first loop (happens often without a barrier before the first loop), there will be a dangling non-blocking receive request that needs to be cancelled and freed.

As for the ideal solution, MPI does provide the so-called single-sided memory operations, but those are not exposed in `mpi4py`, I guess because poking into other processes' memory doesn't bode well with managed languages like Python.

Comment: I have a bit of problem understanding how a `"Done"` message could be received in the first loop. Since there is a barrier before the master worker sends the final message, shouldn't all the workers be out of the first loop by then? Also, just to be sure, messages will arrive in the same order as they where sent if you are not specifying the tag, right?

Comment: In your version, there may be a pending non-blocking receive on exit from the loop. Even after the barrier, if will still be able to match a `"Done"` message. As to the second question, yes, messages sent between two ranks in the same communicator retain their order no matter the tags.